# Extract product code from KB hotfix to use in bootstrapper

Tags: deployment, windows-installer, clickonce, bootstrapper

I need to add KB Hotfix to my application's prerequisites, I'll do that by creating bootstrapper package for it.

To do that first I need to check whether if its already installed or not so I can bypass it.

I need the product code to add new MsiProductCheck in [InstallCheck](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229432%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) then check its value and bypass it if its installed.

Is that ok to use the MsiProductCheck with the KB Hotfixes or should I use another [InstallCheck](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229432%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) ?

Regards

Comment: Just try to install it. If it is already installed, the installer will do nothing. Checking for a specific KB is unreliable because the KB may have been superseded.

Comment: I need to bypass it so I can skip its download

Comment: You can [use scripts like this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387102(v=vs.85).aspx) to see which updates are needed. If you try to check if a specific KB is installed, it will eventually always return "no" because it will get rolled up into a service pack or something like that, at which point the KB is obsolete.

Comment: if I did that I need to use External Checks, is that mean that I can't use the "MsiProductCheck" to determine whether if that hotfix installed or not, I think there should some way to use the "Parameterinfo.xml" file inside the package to get its "Product Code" and create "MsiProductCheck" or other Install check for it..

Comment: What about just packaging the KB with your app (rather than making the user download it)?

Comment: The KB is related to .Net itself "KB2640103" that includes hotfix for known issue, I did it by checking the clr.dll file version and bypass it if the clr.dll version is greater than or equals than "4.0.30319.586"

Comment: This assumes that the user is on the GDR path. If the user has gone to the LDR path, then a higher-version-number GDR update may not have all the fixes from a lower-numbered LDR update. Servicing is complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a number of different types of KBs.

If you don't want to install it, and you know a bit about MSI, of course you can find out the ProductCode, if it is a MSI KB.

Two common types:

*The KB file has suffix .exe* - which includes a .msp (patch) file. You can open the .exe with right mouse button with an unpacker as e.g. 7zip (don't double click, that will install it). Then use a tool like **Insted** (google for it) to look inside the .msp file.
But patches do not have an own ProductCode, they have an own GUID and patch full MSIs which have themselve ProductCodes. Maybe more for MSI experts, this stuff. Both GUIDs are in the Summary information, which is not a normal table.
I don't know that "MsiProductCheck" to judge, what you have to do to use this info.

*The KB file has suffix .msu* (yes, not .msi)-
Then you can read the ProductCode with any MSI editor like Orca (in platform SDK) or Insted (again). Look in the property table, there it is.

Relying on ProductCodes is most of the time not to recommend. If you are sure, you want exactly that KB as a prerequisite, it's OK. For other things than KBs, I would not recommend that at all.

Better: If possible, I would search for files/registry changes that the KBs perform, and use that (e.g. a file version or registry GUID) myself in a program to check if it is installed. File versions, if changed, are a good practice, because you are not dependant to only one hotfix, e.g. next time the change is included in a ServicePack or new Windows version, etc.

I have done things like written programs to assure a number of different prerequisites depending on different Windows versions, and I can say, to be perfect, sometimes it is hard work, you can spend weeks and months with.